# Applying for FAANG after completion of MBBS?

Tags: career-path

I have recently applied for undergraduate programs at many universities

and after all, I've got into a medical school for the 4 years MBBS program (MBBS stands for Bachelor of Medicine and Bachelor of Surgery).

However, my dream is to work for Big Tech Companies like Google, Microsoft or IBM, or even NASA or some Big Biotech Companies like Pfizer or AstraZeneca.

But unfortunately, I got rejected from all the CS undergrad programs that I applied to. So, I decided to go for MBBS which is mostly psychology/medicine or Human Biology based. And After I graduated with the MBBS degree, I would like to apply to Big BioTech companies

However, I have no idea if BioTech companies do hire people with MBBS degree? because MBBS degrees are mainly for Doctors

So, Could someone explain with reasons whether I should pursue MBBS if I have a dream to work for BioTech companies or FAANG ? or What would be wiser to do now ?

Comment: If you want to work for FAANG companies, the best strategy would be to have a degree in CS. Can you try to apply for a CS undergraduate program at some other universities ? It does not have to be a super famous university such as MIT, Yale, Harvard, Princeton, etc... I honestly know many people who only get a BS or MS degree in CS from normal state, local city, or  public universities, and are working for FAANG companies.

Comment: What's your goal, exactly?  I mean, you say that you want to work for a big bio-tech company or FAANG, and a simple way to do that would seem to be to apply for a low-level job, e.g. work as a janitor or something.  But assuming that's not precisely what you'd want, then what would be?

Comment: @Nat, My goal is to work for Bio-Tech or FAANG as a higher-level position. And I would like to be in the research field that could be the intersection of Maths and Biology or CS or whatever. Im fine with any scientific or engineering or any Bio research field. So, Is it wise to get a MBBS degree ?

Comment: "Preparations for a non-academic career" is an explicitly off-topic category of question here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Wait, How could this question about MBBS is related to Non-academic ?

Answer (score 1):

Your degree matters less than what actual skills of yours could be used by a company. You may have gained some knowledge about how medicine works and it could be used in a biotech project. Or maybe not. Whatever your circumstances are more specifically, you must be able to answer "what am I bringing to the table". Higher education does not exist solely to make people learn things about the world, and it does not end with a nicely wrapped diploma. No, you get skills enabling you to perform some kind of a job.

Now, I do not advocate for the existing, but rather extreme view of the hands-on approach being all you need. But most certainly, do not pursue degrees for the sake of getting a degree, that would be just wasteful. Instead, think about

- What do you want to do - not in terms of a company or a job title,
  but rather of the job itself - and what skills do you need to perform
  that job?
- What skills do you have and how can you apply them to do
  something interesting?

I would imagine you to need IT-related skills (programming, software architecture) to work for most of the companies you have listed, but they do not necessarily have to be tied to your formal education.

Comment: As for now, I have got into the MBBS program which is related to Medicine or the medical field. So, would it be okay to apply for Big Tech companies with my MBBS degree ? I mean, will these companies ever value this MBBS degree  ?

Comment: They won't value even a CS degree per se if you don't have skills to back it up. And they will be testing those skills. It is believed to help though. But again, you are focusing on the wrong thing - the hiring process is not about looking at the CV and opening the door for the most impressive candidate. It is about finding the best fit for the company or even the team within it. Will getting an MBBS degree make you a valuable asset? Explain how. (The same question can and will be asked about any degree).